JSON parsing error in Spring Cloud Gateway
While routing request through Spring Cloud Gateway for some of the response it is giving JSON parsing error and the reason being NonClosingInputStream, does anyone knows the reason behind it.
Tried caching request body with default caching technique

Can you please give more information about this error, how you approach that, what is your setup or architecture

Please take the tour, read How to Ask, and then post a proper minimal reproducible example with all relevant details.
